# Why can't I use the chain rule for multiple variables to differentiate the logarithm of a quotient

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule, implicit-differentiation

Say I want to find the derivative of the below function with respect to x, which equals zero.

$u(x,z) = \ln(\frac{\mathrm{x}^α + \mathrm{z}^{α}}{\mathrm{z}^α}),$$ $$z = h(x) = \mathrm{(a\mathrm{x}^4 + b)}^{(1/3)}$.

$u'(x,z) = 0$.

As x and z are both functions of x, I expect to be able to solve this using the chain rule for multiple variables, however I always end up with the incorrect answer unless I substitute z.

$u'(x,z) = \frac{du}{dx} dx + \frac{du}{dz} dz = 0$.

By using the quotient rule on the logarithm, I end up with the wrong answer according to the textbook unless I substitute z then differentiate. How do you find the total derivative with the quotient rule? Is this even possible?

According to the answer: $x = \mathrm{(3b/a)}^{1/4}$.

I tried:

$u'(x,z) = \Large \frac{\frac{α\cdot\ \mathrm{z}^α\mathrm{x}^{α-1} - (0)}{\mathrm{z}^{α^{2}}} + \frac{\mathrm{z}^α α\mathrm{{z}^{α-1} -(\mathrm{x}^α + \mathrm{z}^{α}) α\cdot\mathrm{z}^{α-1}}} {\mathrm{z}^{α^{2}}}\frac{du}{dz}}{\frac{\mathrm{x}^α + \mathrm{z}^{α}}{\mathrm{z}^α}}$

Comment: Please edit to show all your work. Do not use the quotient rule unless you are forced to; I suggest using properties of logarithms instead.

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the question correctly? Also please format consistently.

Comment: @Sam Hi, I have. Apologies for mixing Leibniz and Newton's notation. It feels easier to use Leibniz to display my attempt at the chain rule, as LaTex appears to have no way of specifying the variable of integration, when there are multiple variables.

Comment: @damola3 Yes it does. You can write, e.g., $\int f(x, y) \ dx$ or $\int f(x, y) \ dy.$ If you want a partial derivative, write `\partial` for $\partial.$

Comment: @SeanRoberson Apologies, I meant differentiation. Partials work, though LaTex has no option for a letter or number under the ' in order to specify. I prefer Leibniz, as it's cleaner. I'm just tired having spent over a day on this problem.

Comment: Sometimes you have to sacrifice cleanliness for clarity. Never use primes for functions of several variables. As suggested, just use properties of logarithms to write $u(x, z) = \ln (x^\alpha + z^\alpha) - \ln x^\alpha.$ Then take derivatives in $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x,z)=\ln\left(\frac{x^\alpha + z^\alpha}{z^\alpha}\right) = \ln(x^\alpha + z^\alpha) - \ln(z^\alpha), z=h(x)=(ax^4 + b)^{1/3}$ . Then
$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
$$= \frac{\alpha x^{\alpha - 1}}{x^\alpha + z^\alpha} + \left(\frac{\alpha z^{\alpha - 1}}{x^\alpha + z^\alpha} - \frac{\alpha}{z}\right)\left(\frac{4 a x^3}{3 \left(a x^4+b\right)^{2/3}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\alpha  x^{\alpha -1} }{3 \left(x^{\alpha }+z^{\alpha }\right)}\left(3-\frac{4 a x^4}{z \left(a x^4+b\right)^{2/3}}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\alpha  x^{\alpha -1}}{3 \left(\left(a x^4+b\right)^{\alpha /3}+x^{\alpha }\right)}\left(3-\frac{4 a x^4}{a x^4+b}\right)$$
Now if this is set to $0$, we get that
$$3-\frac{4 a x^4}{a x^4+b}=0 \implies ax^4=3b \implies x=\left(\frac{3b}{a}\right)^{1/4}$$
This is why I asked if you copied everything correctly, since my answer is coming out to be different form the one you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought you meant the original question. Your answer is correct. Apologies that I'm tired.